# Can I run NVIDIA DeepStream SDK in Windows Server 2019?

Tags: docker, nvidia, docker-image, nvidia-docker, nvidia-deepstream

**System**: I've a Windows Server 2019 OS installed with a [NVIDIA Tesla T4 Tensor Core GPU](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/data-center/tesla-t4/).

**Goal**: Planning to read real time streaming videos from an IP camera and to further process frame by frame. Goal is to leverage NVIDIA DeepStream SDK, but issue is, it [isn't available](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/deepstream-sdk-for-windows-os/59062) for Windows OS. So, I'm thinking on the docker lines, but since am very new to docker containers, would like to know if I can install a docker on Windows and can run this [deepstream docker image](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:deepstream) on that.

If not, is there any way I can run this Linux based DeepStream docker image on Windows? Any help shall be greatly acknowledged.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you have everything in the docker.

Comment: Can you elaborate, how? I tried this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/deploy-containers-on-server), but not working fine...

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with the windows server before it should be the same as a docker in Linux VM.

First, you need to pull docker images for deepstream

`docker pull nvcr.io/nvidia/deepstream:5.0-dp-20.04-triton`

and then try to run sample apps provided in the docker image.

Refer [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/dev-guide/index.html#page/DeepStream_Development_Guide/deepstream_quick_start.html#wwpID0E0HC0HA) for the procedure.

if you are interested in python apps you can check sample apps [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps).

Note:- make sure you are able to access display from inside the container cause deepstream use eglsink in their samples app which will try to open a display window on your screen or you can change the sink type to filesink if you want to save it is a file.

Refer [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/dev-guide/index.html#page/DeepStream_Development_Guide/deepstream_app_config.3.2.html#) for available plugins and their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the post in Nivida forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/deepstream-using-docker-on-windows/204612), Windows not supported.

As alternative, I wonder if anyone used [the Nvidia Graph Composer](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/dev-guide/graphtools-docs/docs/text/GraphComposer_app_Workflow.html) in Windows.